# char WM_KEYDOWN showing up as number and no capitol letters when hard coded

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm writing an app that can send keystrokes to another application.  I have some of it sort of working when I hard code the text that I want to send.  However when I use `argv[]` to get the text from the arguments list it no longer sends the text and instead numbers or nothing shows up.  I think the problem lies in taking the text from `char*` and putting it into the `std::string` before parsing that and sending each char to the function that sends the keystroke to the awaiting application.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

HWND SendIt (DWORD dwProcessID, const char key)
{
    HWND hwnd = NULL;
    do {
        hwnd = FindWindowEx(NULL, hwnd, NULL, NULL);
        DWORD dwPID = 0;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwPID);
        if (dwPID == dwProcessID) {
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_KEYDOWN,key, 1);
        }
    } while (hwnd != 0);
    return hwnd;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        cout << "Please provide a PID# and a String of Charaters to pass to the PID#.\n";
        cout << "Examples:\n";
        cout << "RegTSM.exe 16855 WP3C94\n";
        cout << "RegTSM.exe 16855 \"type this into the PID Handle\" \n";
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        DWORD PID;
        std::string sPID;
        std::string text;
        sPID = argv[1];
        PID = atof(sPID.c_str());
        text = argv[2];
        text += "\r";
        //std::string text = "WN403A\r";

        for (char & key : text) {
            SendIt(PID, key);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I run the code above and provide the PID of a cmd.exe process and some text like the letter 'a' it will print 1 in the cmd.exe process I targeted.

If I use the commented section `std::string text = "WN403A\r";` instead as the input to the `for (char & key : text)` then it will work fine (except for not producing capitol letters, which I need) and type out `wn403a`.

1. command line arguments not producing the actual characters provided.
2. even when string is hard coded the output to the other cmd.exe window is not in capital letters.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: [You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).  Even if you could, your code is not accounting for the possibility of the target process having multiple windows, or switching between windows while you are sending keystrokes. More importantly, you are only sending `WM_KEYDOWN` messages, not any `WM_KEYUP` messages, you are not sending virtual keycodes, or taking lowercase vs uppercase into account (which requires sending additional keystrokes to handle the shift key).

Comment: It does work with the hard coded string (just no caps which I need).

Comment: To simulate uppercase chars, you need to simulate shift key presses.  You really should rethink your approach, though. Don't use `PostMessage()` at all, use `SendInput()` instead. However, it doesn't allow you to target specific windows, so use `WM_SETTEXT` or [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) instead.  Find the specific target window, and then send your text directly to it, not through simulated keystrokes.

Comment: I'll include a WM_KEYUP in the function that is a good point, and the shift key as well.  Still would like to understand why it sends letters when hard coded and junk when taking input from argv[]

Comment: Well, since you have not bothered showing what your actual input is, or what the "junk" looks like, nobody can tell you why you are seeing what you are seeing.

Comment: Just found something out!  When I execute the program with "regtsm 2256 asdf"  the cmd.exe that I'm targeting shows up with "16" but if I use "regtsm 2256 ASDF" I get "asdf" in the cmd.exe.  I think that will clue me in on what to do.

Comment: `WM_KEYDOWN`/`UP` sends [virtual key codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731.aspx), NOT characters (`WM_CHAR` sends characters instead). ASCII `'A'` (0x41) is the same value as virtual key `VK_A`, whereas `'a'` (0x61) is the same value as `VK_NUMPAD1`. Likewise, `'S'` (0x53) = `VK_S` whereas `'s'` (0x73) = `VK_F4`, `'D'` (0x44) = `VK_D` whereas `'d'` (0x64) = `VK_NUMPAD4`, and `'F'` (0x46) = `VK_F` whereas `'f'` (0x66) = `VK_NUMPAD6`.

Comment: The same applies to `"WN403A\r"`, where `'W'` (0x57) = `VK_W`, `'N'` (0x4E) = `VK_N`, `'4'` (0x34) = `VK_4`, `'0'` (0x30) = `VK_0`, `'3'` (0x33) = `VK_3`, `'A'` (0x41) = `VK_A`, and `'\r'` (0x0D) = `VK_RETURN`.  Since you are not sending down/up messages for the `VK_SHIFT` key, you end up with lowercase letters instead of uppercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

As Raymond Chen blogged:

[You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Even if you could do it reliably, your code is NOT:

1. accounting for the possibility of the target process having multiple windows.  Or even that it might switch between windows while you are in the middle of sending keystrokes.  You are sending your key messages to random windows within the process, and even then only to top-level windows, not to any particular child control windows that have keyboard input at the time of the send.
2. sending any `WM_KEYUP` messages, only `WM_KEYDOWN` messages.
3. sending virtual key codes.  `WM_KEYDOWN`/`UP` do not operate on characters, they operate on key codes and scan codes instead.  `WM_CHAR`, on the other hand, operates on characters.
4. taking lowercase vs uppercase into account, which requires simulating the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key being held down while sending an uppercase character.

You really should rethink your approach.  Don't use `PostMessage()` at all, you should be using [`SendInput()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) instead.  However, it doesn't allow you to target a specific window, so you would have to use [`WM_SETTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632644.aspx) or even [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) to send your text directly to the target window.

That being said, if you insist on using `PostMessage()`, then try something more like this instead:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cctype>

struct MyEnumInfo
{
    DWORD dwProcessID;
    HWND hwndFocus;
};

BOOL CALLBACK FindFocusedWindow(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MyEnumInfo *mei = (MyEnumInfo*)lParam;

    DWORD dwPID = 0;
    DWORD dwThreadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwPID);
    if (dwPID == mei->dwProcessID)
    {
        GUITHREADINFO gti = {0};
        gti.cbSize = sizeof(gti);
        if (GetGUIThreadInfo(dwThreadID, &gti))
        {
            mei->hwndFocus = gti.hwndFocus;
            if (mei->hwndFocus)
                return FALSE;
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}

HWND SendIt(DWORD dwProcessID, const std::string &text)
{
    if (text.empty())
        return NULL;

    MyEnumInfo mei;
    mei.dwProcessID = dwProcessID;
    mei.hwndFocus = NULL;

    EnumWindows(&FindFocusedWindow, (LPARAM)&mei);

    if (!mei.hwndFocus)
        return NULL;

    LPARAM lParamShift = MapVirtualKey(VK_SHIFT, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC) << 16;
    LPARAM lParamCtrl = MapVirtualKey(VK_CONTROL, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC) << 16;
    LPARAM lParamAlt = MapVirtualKey(VK_MENU, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC) << 16;

    for (const char& key : text)
    {
        SHORT code = VkKeyScanA(key);
        BYTE vk = LOBYTE(code);
        BYTE shift = HIBYTE(code);

        if ((vk != -1) && (shift != -1))
        {
            if (shift & 1) PostMessage(mei.hwndFocus, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_SHIFT, lParamShift);
            if (shift & 2) PostMessage(mei.hwndFocus, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_CONTROL, lParamCtrl);
            if (shift & 4) PostMessage(mei.hwndFocus, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_MENU, lParamAlt);

            LPARAM lParamKey = MapVirtualKey(vk, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC) << 16;
            PostMessage(mei.hwndFocus, WM_KEYDOWN, vk, lParamKey);
            PostMessage(mei.hwndFocus, WM_KEYUP, vk, lParamKey | 0xC0000001);

            if (shift & 1) PostMessage(mei.hwndFocus, WM_KEYUP, VK_SHIFT, lParamShift | 0xC0000001);
            if (shift & 2) PostMessage(mei.hwndFocus, WM_KEYUP, VK_CONTROL, lParamCtrl | 0xC0000001);
            if (shift & 4) PostMessage(mei.hwndFocus, WM_KEYUP, VK_MENU, lParamAlt | 0xC0000001);
        }
    }

    return mei.hwndFocus;
}

void usage()
{
    std::cout << "Please provide a PID# and a String of Characters to send to the PID#.\n";
    std::cout << "Examples:\n";
    std::cout << "RegTSM.exe 16855 WP3C94\n";
    std::cout << "RegTSM.exe 16855 \"type this into the PID Handle\"\n";
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        usage();
        return 1;
    }

    DWORD PID;
    if (std::sscanf(argv[1], "%u", &PID) != 0) {
        usage();
        return 1;
    }

    std::string text = std::string(argv[2]) + "\r";
    //std::string text = "WN403A\r";

    SendIt(PID, text);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try that tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I visited this project but I wanted to post the code that ended up working.  Thanks to all for comments and education!!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

HWND SendIt (DWORD dwProcessID, const char key)
{
    HWND hwnd = NULL;
    do {
        hwnd = FindWindowEx(NULL, hwnd, NULL, NULL);
        DWORD dwPID = 0;
        DWORD threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwPID);
        if (dwPID == dwProcessID) {
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_CHAR, (WPARAM)key, 0);
        }
    } while (hwnd != 0);
    return hwnd;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        cout << "Please provide a PID# and a String of Charaters to pass to the PID#.\n";
        cout << "Examples:\n";
        cout << "RegTSM.exe 16855 WP3C94\n";
        cout << "RegTSM.exe 16855 \"type this into the PID Handle\" \n";
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
        DWORD PID;
        std::string sPID;
        std::string text;
        sPID = argv[1];
        PID = atof(sPID.c_str());
        text = argv[2];
        text += "\r";

        for (char & key : text) {
            SendIt(PID, key);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```